# Feature Request: Add on perks apart from badges?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Should there be more attractive perks apart from badges?

Awarding something like "Cups" for the best answer of the week or month.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are additional peaks over and above the badges. There are unlockable [Privileges](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) that come in at different reputation levels. They give you the ability to vote, review and even delete posts among other things.